# Switching between Mobile and Desktop site in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, user-agent

I am trying to switch between mobile and desktop site using a toggle button, so I set the appropriate `user-agent`. But once I load the desktop site then I try to load the mobile site by setting the mobile user agent and refreshing the webview. It's not working, but if I type the site again in the search bar it loads the right website.

```
fun setMobileView(context: Context) {
    val tinyDB = TinyDB(context)
    getWebView()?.settings?.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930VC Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    getWebView()?.reload()
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting mobile user agent")
    tinyDB.putBoolean("is_desktop_view", false)
}

fun setDesktopView(context: Context) {
    val tinyDB = TinyDB(context)
    getWebView()?.settings?.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
    getWebView()?.reload()
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting desktop user agent")
    tinyDB.putBoolean("is_desktop_view", true)
}
```

Comment: You could try saving the `userAgentString` from the WebView prior to changing in `setDesktopView()`. Then apply that value back in `setMobileView()` to guard against an incorrect value being applied.

Comment: No I tried it's not working